# I have a zip file. I extracted it and modified some files. How do I list them?

Tags: command-line, zip, diff

Basically I'd like to do a diff and list binary-changed files recursively in the folder. I want to avoid cluttering the filesystem so I think this involves some piping.

I searched some examples but everybody looks for zip-to-zip diff.

---

The real use case is for updating a web application: I want to use the current version `setup-v1.23.zip` file to list customized files to be backupped before overwriting the folder with the content of a newer `setup-v1.75.zip` file from the original vendor.

I will be using PHP's [`shell_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to execute the script file and read the resulting list for further processing.

Comment: do you want to have a `diff` output or just a list of changed files?

Comment: i'm ok with just the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare the `crc32` checksums:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

target_dir="/path/to/target/"
archive="/path/to/archive.zip"

# Loop through files in archive
while IFS= read -r filename; do
    # Check if file exists in target:
    [ -f "${target_dir}/${filename}" ] || { echo "new: '$filename'"; continue; }
    # Get CRC32 Checksum from target
    crc_in_target=$(crc32 "${target_dir}/${filename}")
    # Get CRC32 Checksum from zip
    crc_in_zip=$(unzip -vqq a.zip "$filename" | awk '{print $7}')
    # Compare Checksums
    [ "$crc_in_target" = "$crc_in_zip" ] || echo "changed: '$filename'"
done < <(unzip -Z -1 "$archive")
```

Note:
 This might have problems when the filenames contain a newline character.

Well, I'm pretty sure you can do the same with `php` directly without calling the shell. You may ask for help with `php` at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I get `check.sh: line 14: syntax error near unexpected token \`<'`
and `check.sh: line 14: \`done) < <(unzip -Z -1 "$archive")'`

Comment: sorry, the code is bash. I added the correct shebang

Comment: It works now. Thank you! I will probably implement it in php.at a later time.

Comment: btw is there a way to skip the first folder level of the zip file? for example when the zip contains `/build/index.html` that is deployed to `/app/index.html` and I set `target_dir` to `app/`